# Finding all functions in current workspace

Tags: r, function, workspace

I'd like to find all functions in my current workspace and thought about using `is.function` for that purpose.

The "problem" is that `is.function` expects a true R *object*, not the character string *name* of an object.

That's my solution, but using `eval(substitute(...))` seems a bit involved. Any ideas for a more straight forward way or is that the only way this can be done?

**Example content**

```
x <- TRUE
y <- 10
foo1 <- function() message("hello world!")
foo2 <- function() message("hello world again!")
```

**Finding all function objects**

```
wscontent <- ls(all.names=TRUE)
funs <- sapply(wscontent, function(ii) {
    eval(substitute(is.function(OBJ), list(OBJ=as.name(ii))))
})
> funs
     foo1      foo2      funs wscontent         x         y 
     TRUE      TRUE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about

```
lsf.str()
```

which should list all functions.

Comment: +1 for the pointer to `lsf.str()`, didn't know that one before! This one seems to get me exactly what I'm after with just a one-liner: `funs <- as.character(lsf.str())`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Rappster, depending on what you want to do with the result, using `as.character` might not be necessary, since `lsf.str` returns essentially a character vector of function names. It's just that the object is of class `ls_str`, for which there is a `print` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
funs <- sapply(wscontent, function(x) is.function(get(x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a more general toy a while back:

```
lstype<-function(type='closure'){
inlist<-ls(.GlobalEnv)
if (type=='function') type <-'closure'
typelist<-sapply(sapply(inlist,get),typeof)
return(names(typelist[typelist==type]))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use eapply:

```
which(unlist(eapply(.GlobalEnv, is.function)))
```

... or sapply with as.list:

```
which(sapply(as.list(.GlobalEnv), is.function))
```